# JavaScript async iterator join/reduce

Tags: javascript

I have an async iterator like this:

```
async function* getLines() {
  for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    const response = await fetch('/resource/' + index);
    const data = await response.text();
    yield data;
  }
}
```

I am able to consume it using `for await`:

```
let source = '';
for await (const line of getLines()) {
  console.log('line');
  source += line + '\n';
}

return source;
```

But I wonder if there is a way to use something like `Array.from` or `[...]` to achieve the same joining of items from an async iterator to a string.

`Array.from(await getLines())` nor `[...getLines()]` make sense by themselves as the generator itself is not to be awaited by the individual items, like in the `for await` construct. Is there anything like `Array.fromAwait(getLines())` or is that something I have to roll on my own like in the example where I use `for await`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current specification does not support operators like `.reduce` on async iterators and unless you are on Node (in which case you can do AsyncIterator -> Readable.from -> async iterator) you will have to use a user-land library like [axax](https://github.com/jamiemccrindle/axax).

There is a [tc39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) toadd iterator helpers. With those you will be able to do:

```
const source = await getLines().reduce((l, cur) => l + cur);
```

It is currently stage 2 and you can use a polyfill.

Comment: Can you expand on `Readable.from`? I'm not quite sure how I'd use that.

Comment: `Readable.from` converts an async iterator to a Node.js stream, you can transform that and use the fact the stream itself is async iterable to get an async iterator back. See https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_readable_from_iterable_options

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum But readable streams don't have a `reduce` method either? I must be missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [IX (interactive extension)](https://github.com/ReactiveX/IxJS) it is a library created by the RxJs community that has the same operators in RxJs but is used with sync and async iterators

Answer (score 0):

These days, it can be much simpler, with the help of iterables, and the variety of libraries that support them.

The example below is based on one such library, called [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops):

```
import {pipeAsync, map, reduce, wait} from 'iter-ops';

const indexes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; // your resource id-s

const i = pipeAsync(
    indexes,
    map(a => fetch('/resource/' + a).then(r => r.text())),
    wait(), // resolve each request
    reduce((r, c) => r + '\n' + c)
); //=> AsyncIterable<string>

// test:
(async function () {
    const source = await i.first; // iterate, and wait for the first value
    console.log(source); // all the lines joint together
})();
```

It is also the fastest way to convert a list of source id-s into the final data.

P.S. I am the author.